# $\cap_{g\in G}A^{g}$ contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group, and $A$ a subgroup of $G$. If the index $\left|G:A\right|$ is less than some prime divisor $p$ of the order of $G$, prove that $\cap_{g\in G}A^{g}$ contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Help me with some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

Suppose $\;|G|=p^nm\;,\;\;(m,p)=1\;$ , and denote by $\;Syl_p(G)\;$ the set of all Sylow $\;p$- subgroups of $\;G\;$:

$$\begin{align*}\text{I}\;\;\bullet&\;\;\bigcap_{g\in G}A^g\lhd G\\{}\\
\text{II}\;\;\bullet&\;\;N\lhd G\;\;\wedge\;\;P\in Syl_p(G)\implies N\cap P\in Syl_p(N)\end{align*}$$

Hints for I: set $\;X:=\{xA\;;\;x\in G\}=\;$ the set of left cosets of A, and define an action (the regular one) of $\;G\;$ on $\;X\;$ by $\;g\cdot (xA)\mapsto(gx)A\;$ . Let $\phi:G\to Sym_X\;$  be the corresponding group homomorphism. Show that $\;\bigcap_{g\in G}A^g=\ker\phi\;$

Hints for II: Use the isomorphism theorems and do some arithmetic with the orders and the given data, for example:

$$N/\left(N\cap P\right)\cong NP/P\;\;\ldots$$

Comment: Why did you assume $G$ is a $p$-group?

Comment: that's a typo. Edited now, thanks.

Comment: I understood all of the two results that you told. But why those lead to the main result?

Comment: @user109584 ,  We're given that $$\frac{p^nm}{|A|}=\frac{|G|}{|A|}=[G:A]<p\iff |A|>p^{n-1}m $$

and this already means $\;p^n\mid |A|\;$ . Making now $\;G\;$ act on the left cosets of $\;A\;$ we get a corresponding homom. $\;\phi:G\to S_{[G:A]}\;$ whose kernel is precisely the core of $\;A\;,\;\;\cap_{g\in G}A^g=\ker\phi\;$, which is the maximal normal subgroup of $\;G\;$ contained in $\;A\;$, and note that $\;p^n\;$ divides this subgroup, since otherwise

$$G/\ker\phi\cong T\le S_{[G:A]}$$

and p$\;\nmid [G:A]!\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider the action of $G$ by conjugation on the set of subgroups conjugated with $H$, and find its kernel.